# New Apple Certs 12/17

Tags: parse-platform

On 12/17/2015, Apple improved their APNS process https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172015b.

Part of this included changing the name on certificates.

**Production**

- Old: Apple Production IOS Push Services
- New: Apple Push Services

When uploading a p12 to Parse, the following error is received:

> Unsupported certificate type. Common Name (CN) must contain one of: Apple Production IOS Push Services, Apple Development IOS Push Services, Pass Type ID, Apple Development Mac Push Services, Apple Production Mac Push Services.

Is anyone else running into this, or does anyone know the timeframe for being able to upload these certificates to Parse?

Comment: Same problem here :(

Comment: So sorry to hear, but thanks for confirming that it's not just me!

Comment: what did parse's support say?

Comment: @vikingosegundo... no this is as of yesterday. The certs you generate in the member center have changed. The common name is different.

Comment: hey @JimJeffers, it's been a long time. I hope you are fine. Though I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @vikingosegundo indeed! Well as of yesterday -- the common name of the certs issued by apple for push notifications have changed. You can only create a universal cert for production/sandbox in the member center. The validation on Parse is out of date. It's looking for the CN on certs apple used to issue that were production / staging specific. In the link you posted -- I believe that user exported his PK and his cert as a package so it was a different issue. Hope all is well in Berlin!

Comment: As I understand the symptoms are the same, the error message is the same, and both were reported within 18 hours. I assume it to have the same cause.

Comment: @vikingosegundo my bad. I had too many SO tabs opened and thought you were linking to a different issue all together. Thanks!